# Regex check a user input string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement, not-operator

I have a if statement that checks if the user left the input empty and did not enter the correct pattern (which is essentially a student number). However, it seems when I input a random mash of words and number, it still passes, as if it is not checking the regex validation.

```
    var idInput = formHandle.f__id; //this connects back to my HTML form
    var studentNum = /(n|N)\d{8}/;
    if (idInput.value === "" && !studentNum.test(idInput)) {
        idInput.style.background = 'red';
        idInput.focus();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You should separate these conditions and check them individually

Comment: Try `if (idInput.value === "" || !studentNum.test(idInput.value))`

Comment: Also you might want to add ^$ to your regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your `&&` should be an `||`: If the input is empty *or* doesn't match the regex. Since the regex won't match an empty string, you don't need the `idInput.value === ""` check though.
2. `!studentNum.test(idInput)` should be `!studentNum.test(idInput.value)`
3. You forgot the anchors `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) in the regex. Without them, this just searches for "n or N followed by 8 digits" *anywhere* in the string.

Fixed code:

```js
var idInput = formHandle.f__id; //this connects back to my HTML form
var studentNum = /^(n|N)\d{8}$/;
if (!studentNum.test(idInput.value)) {
    idInput.style.background = 'red';
    idInput.focus();
    return false;
}
```

(side note, is there any reason to use `var` instead of `let` / `const`?)

Comment: Thank you! It works. However, after I posted the question, I switch the && to || and it went from accepting any input to rejecting every one. Could you explain why that happened? Once again, thanks! (To answer your side note: I am new to JS, and currently var is all we have been using).

Comment: @jaalle - did you use _idInput.value_ in the regex test() ?

Comment: @sln yes i did use that in the regex test

Comment: @jaalle - Although not necessary to check for the empty string since test() will fail if empty (based on the regex), for readability you could just change your line with a || and it will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

*I would have just left this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.*

Based on your question, I believe your code simply has a logic error.

As far as I can tell, you want to enter the if statement in the case that the input is invalid (so it is empty, or violates the regex). However, you are using `&&` instead of `||`.

For your test case, if you enter random characters, then `idInput.value !== ""`, so the if statement will not be executed.